# Union, order by and RAND() in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to have a union of two request BUT the order by rand() of the second one doesn't work..

```
(select * from survey 
where is_priority = 1)
union all (
  select * from (
    select * from survey 
    order by rand() 
    ) as t );
```

The result look like this :

[image]

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Rows in a subquery are considered unordered, so the `ORDER BY` in your second subquery is superfluous. Result rows of a query without an `ORDER BY` clause at the end are also considered unordered. So there is nothing in your query to suggest how the result rows shall be ordered. Then, how can `select * from survey ...` result in only one column `id_survey` when there is obviously at least one more column (`is_priority`) in the table? And please don't past images, copy and paste the result as text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I speculate that you want `is_priority = 1` first followed by the rest in random order.

If so, you should not do this with `union all`.  Just add the right keys to the `order by`:

```
select s.*
from survey s
order by (s.is_priority = 1) desc,  -- put priority 1 first in the result set
         rand();
```

Admittedly, this puts the top priority rows in random order (amongst them).  But you haven't specified an order for them (and this is a non-issue if there is only one row where the priority condition is true).

Comment: "I speculate that you want is_priority = 1 first followed by the rest in random order." Yes exaclty ! But your request doesn't work .. I don't understand the "rand()" without "order by" and just after a ","

Comment: @arthur-28: That was obviously a typo. I've edited the answer and replaced `WHERE` by `ORDER BY`. The query should work now. Gordon's query makes use of MySQL's true = 1 , false = 0. So sorting by `(s.is_priority = 1) desc` puts the records where the condition is true first.